# WebClient not download image in method DownoloadFile() c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to set a wallpaper, recovering the path from the Windows registry, I'm doing it in a production environment and I can not see the error, and the log shows no error.

I tried to set a time because the path is connected to a server, there is stored image but I can not set the wallpaper

```
var url = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ITManager", "wallpaper", "");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {

                ScreenSaver.WebClientEx cliente = new ScreenSaver.WebClientEx();
                cliente.Timeout = 150000;
                System.IO.Stream s = cliente.OpenRead(url);

                WriteFileLog("Wallpaper: " + url);
                System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(s);
                string tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "wallpaper.bmp");
                img.Save(tempPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you open the URL that you log in a browser?  If that line is not logged at all, move it to right under `var url = ...` Also you are not disposing of your stream. Lookup the `using` keywword.

Comment: Hi @Eric j, yes the url in browser show the img